# Can the height of two density distributions be interpreted in a meaningful way?

Tags: data-visualization, density-function

I created the following density plot for both values of a binary variable. The variable represents unrealised gains. If a (unrealised) position in a wallet (cryptocurrency) is at a gain it takes the value 1 and 0 otherwise. The value on the x axis represents the holdingtime, i.e. the time that passed since the position was opened.

[image]

The absolute frequency of unrealised losses is far higher, therefore I created a density plot in order to make the two curves more comparable. I interpret thehigher density for unrealised losses at the bginning as: unrealised losses tend to have shorter holding times whereas unrealised gains have longer holding times.

Is such an interpretation correct and even possible?

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit:

As suggested, here the same plot with a log-transfomred values for the x axis:

[image]

If I see that correctly, this confirms my interpretation?

Comment: I suggest trying taking a log of the holding time and comparing again. It might be easier.

Comment: Be careful of what your software does for values near the minimum. Some probability is quite possibly being smoothed away with no correction for a boundary. For that and other reasons I support the suggestion of working on logarithmic scale.

Comment: A probability plot (based on the log values) will give more detailed information about how the empirical distributions differ.